# Does Sequelize support custom serializers/de-serializers

Tags: sequelize.js

I'd like to do a small transformation of properties on my seqeuelize object instance, does the model support custom serializer/de-serializers?

For instance if I am storing a csv string in a property in the database for say latLng : "40,40" and I want to de-serialize it to an array [40,40] in the object - and vice-versa for when I save the model.

So I'd want to set custom serializer/deserializer for specific properties.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/4186 will go at least some of the way.

However, it will only provide different deserializers at column type level, not at property level. Meaning that you can only define one deserializer per type in the db (one for `VARCHAR`, one for `INT` etc.)